# Gracefully terminate a process on Windows

Tags: windows, go, service, process

I'm writing a server application in Go, and using a wrapper to run it as a Windows service.

There's a need to gracefully shut down the server (to close resources and connections properly), and in UNIX it would be handled through the SIGTERM signal. No big deal.

Though on Windows things seem very different. I see on [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms811896(v=msdn.10)#ucmgch09_topic3) that signals actually exist on windows (?), and the SIGTERM is defined, though other pages indicate [they don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309984/signal-other-than-sigkill-not-terminating-process-on-windows), or to use other mechanisms like WM_CLOSE.

What is the preferable way to tell a headless process to gracefully terminate? How should it be implemented in Go?

The server is designed to be multiplatform, so the most standard way of doing it is preferable.

Comment: what type of "server" are you planning to run? Will it be a web-server? http could be used to more cleanly initiate a targeted shutdown.

Comment: sending a signal requires hunting down the PID of the running process, which is not always a precise task.

Comment: See the answer, the service wrapper should not know what kind of service the server exposes (I might reuse it in the future)

Comment: I'm having the same problem! I'm trying to do a graceful shutdown when windows initiates shutdown or the user logs out, but I can't seem to capture the signal with `signal.Notify`. So it's just closing it instantly. The documentation mentions Windows and says that it gets converted into a sigterm, but that doesn't appear to be happening.... https://godoc.org/os/signal#hdr-Windows

Comment: @gloriphobia - there are tons of ways to write clean code on Windows, but not necessarily with the same concepts as for other OSes. What is your process? A console app, a Windowed app, a Windows service? You don't terminate a process "gracefully" if that process is not aware you want to terminate it. For example, Windows services (what you seem to call "headless") are expected to answer stop requests from API, or Windows UI, or shutdown. Not sure go or its associated wrappers are aware of that. Also CTRL+C (only for GUI-console app with) is not graceful if app doesn't handle it gracefully.

Comment: There seems to be an official example of a go Windows service with stop command being properly handled: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc and also this: https://github.com/kardianos/service

Comment: You're talking about windows services, that's a different context. Here it's closer to a console use case, especially when debugging the program in the IDE.

Comment: @JohnWhite - It's you who said "a server application in Go, and using a wrapper to run it as a Windows service", not me. That doesn't change the fact CTRL-C is not the solution anyway.

Comment: Apologies, the explanation isn't clear indeed. The windows service *starts* another program, it doesn't have the server code inside. It's a launcher, so that's why it needs to gracefully stop a process.

Comment: @JohnWhite
The issue you're experiencing should've been solved in go 1.14 https://github.com/golang/go/pull/33311

Answer (score 2):

The `go` way to initiate canceling a task/service, is to use the [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package.

So if you want a signal handler to trigger the closing of a task's `context.Context`:

```
func registerSigHandler() context.Context {
        sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(sigCh, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

        rootCtx := context.Background()
        taskCtx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(rootCtx)

        go func() {
                sig := <-sigCh
                log.Println("received signal:", sig)

                // let sub-task know to wrap up: cancel taskCtx
                cancelFn()
        }()

        return taskCtx
}
```

and then pass the returned `taskCtx` on to your worker task for it to listen on.

```
select {
    case <-taskCtx.Done():
        // context was canceled
    default: // poll - rather than block in this example
}
```

Playground [source-code](https://play.golang.org/p/V81mxNDgpOD).

Output:

```
2019/03/10 19:18:51 Worker PID: 33186
2019/03/10 19:18:51 Will terminate on these signals: interrupt terminated
2019/03/10 19:18:51 2019-03-10 19:18:51.018962 -0400 EDT m=+0.001727305
2019/03/10 19:18:52 2019-03-10 19:18:52.022782 -0400 EDT m=+1.005517010
2019/03/10 19:18:53 2019-03-10 19:18:53.019925 -0400 EDT m=+2.002630457

$ kill -INT 33186

2019/03/10 19:18:53 received signal: interrupt
2019/03/10 19:18:53 task context terminated reason: context canceled
2019/03/10 19:18:53 wrapping up task...
2019/03/10 19:18:53 workerTask() exited cleanly
2019/03/10 19:18:53 main exited cleanly
```

**EDIT:**

I tested this on `Windows 10` and the clean-up is triggered when a Ctrl-C is issued from the same console.
Not sure how to send signals externally on Windows - which may be the OP's original issue. Using say `killtask /F /PID 33186` would indeed kill the process without any signal handler being triggered.

Comment: How the problem is handled internally is kind of off topic, the problem is how to actually code the signal handling, the documentation doesn't mention a clear way to do this.

Comment: @JohnWhite updated answer to include a working example of registering signal monitoring & context.Context integration.

Comment: Thanks, this is appreciated. Though you're right, a big part of the original issue is how to trigger it under windows, which is why after struggling for some hours I posted it there. Hope somebody posts a solution for it. The golang library doesn't implement signals for windows. Maybe `taskkill` without flags does it? I'll do some tests.

Comment: I created `windows golang` program to send signals to pids and can confirm `os.Interrupt` (-2) is _not support_ - issued at runtime. `os.Kill` (-9) is supported but as we can see terminates the process without handlers being called.

Comment: This is exactly why I created this question. Apparently go has no mechanism for receiving the signal from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a while, I just wanted to share how I solved it. It's ugly, but the only real way I found. Windows golang programs do listen to a CTRL+C, which is not a signal or anything like it, but it does trigger a graceful shutdown in the go program using the same signal UNIX has.

Here's the relevant code:

```golang
// Create shutdown channel
exitChan := make(chan int)
interruptChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interruptChan, os.Interrupt)
select {
case exitCode := <-exitChan:
    os.Exit(exitCode)
case <-interruptChan:
    // This works in Windows if ctrl-c is invoked. It sucks though
    svr.Stop()
    os.Exit(-1)
}
```

To trigger the CTRL+C given the process, I use a small program called windows-kill.exe

```golang
// Windows is "special" and we need to use a library for killing processes gracefully
// Unfortunately setting up the C++ library with go is a hassle, so we resort to a CLI tool
ex, _ := os.Executable()
cmdPath := filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(ex), "windows-kill.exe")
cmd := exec.CommandContext(context.Background(), cmdPath, "-SIGINT", strconv.Itoa(l.proc.Pid))

err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Here's the repo of the library and tool: https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill

Comment: CTRL+C is only valid for console process and is not particularly graceful to the app if app doesn't handle it. It can also be handled so it does nothing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals

Comment: If you're writing go code, it's highly likely you're on console anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using *nix constructs and functions to Windows is generally bad and prone to weird tricks that may or may not work.

The proper way to cleanup on shutdown a GUI application is the handling of [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) and [WM_ENDSESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-endsession).
Also, you have flexibility on generic shut-down mechanism, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutting-down).

The proper way to get notified if you are a service is the service handler of your console application (SERVICE_STOPPED). For more, see [Writing a ServiceMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/writing-a-servicemain-function).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running some form of web-services, may be better to use the web-service itself to initiate a shutdown, as tracking PIDS for signals can get messy.

To stop a http web-service, simply add a route like this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/shutdown",
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // stops server - may want to add admin credentials check here!
            srv.Shutdown(context.Background())
        })
```

Playground [source-code](https://play.golang.org/p/457poBXQlTT) example.

```
2019/03/10 16:58:15 Listening on: :8080

$ curl 'localhost:8080/shutdown'

2019/03/10 17:04:17 Listening on: :8080
2019/03/10 17:04:19 exited cleanly
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's even more messy, as I would need to first authenticate and then issue the shutdown command. Keeping the pid is cleaner and simpler. Plus it would make it necessary to know the listening address from the service wrapper, breaking encapsulation (it shouldn't even know it's a web server)

Comment: with a web-services - you can access this remotely without needing remote-shell access. If you are deploying this on multiple architectures - a web-service would be your cleanest interface. Even if your underlying server is not a http service, you could employ the above technique to listen for shutdown events.

Comment: The use case would break for any application that isn't a web server. As I have another (non web server) program that needs to run as a service (and shutdown gracefully with the OS), this isn't a viable option, rather a quick hack to make it work temporarily.

Comment: @JohnWhite I've dug through a ton of how Windows handles services etc. I don't think this is supported in Go right now. I hate to be that guy but I think you might have to break the box - go with a creative solution. By that I mean, you could look at running it in Linux Hyper-v VM with Docker installed. Doing so would mean that the Go app would get the the OS signal and Hyper-v would signal the VM on shutdown.

Comment: My answer here solved the problem. Yeah it's odd, but it works perfectly, apparently go listens to the ctrl+c and turns it into a signal.

Answer (score 0):

Signaling is implemented on Windows but Unix signals are unavailable.
There is an [example](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/signal/signal_windows_test.go) in the signal package of golang for Windows to send a Ctrl-Break. It is refactored for interactive use [here](https://github.com/iWdGo/sigint-windows).